# Mongoose aggregate match nested document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schemas:

```
var PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    idol: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    views: [ String ],
    likes: [ String ],
    ...
});


var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    ...
});
```

and I have this following aggregate query:

```
Post.aggregate([
    { $match : { '$idol.name' : new RegExp(query, 'gi') } },
    { $skip : page * 20 },
    { $limit : 20 }
], function(err, posts) {}
```

This code is returning the following error:

```
[MongoError: exception: bad query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $idol.name]
```

Is there a way to match something from a nested document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the $ in '$idol.name', just use 'idol.name'. That should take care of the error, however, I don't think this work as you're not actually storing the user object inside each post, but only the ObjectId. Meaning when Mongo tries to aggregate, it will only see the ObjectId, rather than the user.

Comment: I know that. I just need to know if there is a way to populate on aggregation framework using mongoose.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not possible. Aggregate() is a MongoDB operation, whereas populate() is a high-level Mongoose abstraction. Calling populate() is akin to calling two Mongo find() calls. Mongo cannot join across collections by itself.